# 4 compounds in equilibrium with one another - determine their equilibrium concentrations

Tags: equilibrium, concentration

I know that if I have two compounds in equilibrium and I know $\mathrm{\Delta G}$, then I can use $$\mathrm{\Delta G=-RTlnK}$$
to determine the concentrations of the two components at equilibrium.  I have 4 compounds that are all in equilibrium with one another
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{\Delta G(1,4)} ~&= ~~~3.41~ \mathrm{kcal/mol}\\
\mathrm{\Delta G(3,1)}~&=-2.21~ \mathrm{kcal/mol}\\
\mathrm{\Delta G(2,3)}~&=-0.46~ \mathrm{kcal/mol}\\
\end{aligned}

I applied the equation sequentially and found that 
\begin{aligned}%
[1]~&=~0.34\%\\
[2]~&=~29.1\%\\
[3]~&=~13.5\%\\
[4]~&=~57\%\\
\end{aligned}

Are those the correct concentrations? Is there an "easy" way to do it?

Comment: I am linking [my question](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/14617/4945) to this post, since they are very related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case anyone else travels this road...

Using $\mathrm{\Delta G~=~-RTlnK_{eq}}$ and the 3 $\mathrm{\Delta G's}$ supplied above, we find that
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{K^{1/4}_{eq}}~&=~0.003\\
\mathrm{K^{3/1}_{eq}}~&=~40.749\\
\mathrm{K^{2/3}_{eq}}~&=~2.163\\
\end{aligned}
We also know that the concentrations of the 4 species must total to 1

$${[1] + [2] + [3] + [4] = 1}$$

so we have the following 4 equations and 4 unknowns
\begin{aligned}%
[1]~ &=~~~ 0.003 ~[4]\\
[3]~ &=~ 40.749 ~[1]\\
[2]~ &=~~~ 2.163 ~[3]\\
[1] + [2] + [3] + [4]~ &=~ 1\\
\end{aligned}
solving for the 4 concentrations yields
\begin{aligned}%
[1]~ &=~~~ 0.23\%\\
[2]~ &=~ 20.27\%\\
[3]~ &=~~~ 9.37\%\\
[4]~ &=~ 70.13\%\\
\end{aligned}